# Retrieve rows in a dataframe containing words from another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matching

Am trying to retrieve rows in a dataframe containing words from another dataframe. Have attached the .csv files in the link below. I have tried this but it gives me only the single words:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sentiment_words = pd.read_csv('sentiment_words.csv')
tokens = pd.read_csv('tokens.csv')

tokens[tokens['token'].isin(sentiment_words['sentiment_words'])]

Out[201]:
               Class8    Class9         token  
    4156     0.004092  0.014243      abnormal  
    4421     0.000000  0.013170       abolish  
    4500     0.042788  0.062791    abominable
```

The output I want is similar to below just that I would like to replace the "not" with words in the **sentiment_words** dataframe

```
tokens[tokens['token'].str.contains("not")]

           Class8    Class9                  token  
210      0.000000  0.000000        aaand annnother  
396      0.000000  0.006581               aang not  
459      0.000000  0.000000            aardman not  
624      0.000000  0.000000              aaron not  
1147     0.000000  0.007496      abandoned another  
2301     0.000000  0.000000           abducted not
```

sentiment_words.csv : https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2ya5lr4wgl940y/sentiment_words.csv?dl=0
tokens.csv: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wdvprygmnm13lwd/tokens.csv?dl=0

Have been spending several hours searching online but no methods so far so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The 2nd file you posted is 300MB+, how about sharing a smaller sized one?

Comment: My apologies but Its dealing with big data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing nrows to `pd.read_csv()` I was able to make a sample code with your dl-links. Is this what you want?

```
import pandas as pd

url1 = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/y2ya5lr4wgl940y/sentiment_words.csv?raw=1'
url2 = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/wdvprygmnm13lwd/tokens.csv?raw=1'

sentiment_words = pd.read_csv(url1)
tokens = pd.read_csv(url2, nrows=1000) # Limit rows read to 1000

# Create regex pattern
# We need to replace * and + as they will not work without escape in regex
pat = '|'.join(sentiment_words['sentiment_words'].str.replace('*','\*')
                                                 .str.replace('+','\+'))

# Create mask and apply overwriting old values
m2 = tokens['token'].str.contains(pat, regex=True)
tokens = tokens.loc[m2]

tokens
```

Comment: Yes this works thanks! As I thought regex is needed to do the filtering. (There's just a small issue that some words appear even though they do not contain words in the sentiment_words but at least this code can filter out the unnecessary words)

Answer (score 1):

try converting the sentiment words to a list via:

```
sentiment_list = sentiment_words['sentiment_words'].tolist()
```

Then, try and match the words using this:

```
result = tokens[tokens['token'].str.contains('|'.join(sentiment_list))]
```

Note: i didn't download the large csv file, but this should work i think

Comment: Yes I tried this but it gives an error. [error: multiple repeat]